# What's the ObjC version of @discardableResult declaration in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, llvm

In Swift 3, there will be a warning when return value didn't used. The @discardableResult declaration will suppress the feature.

How do I declare this in ObjC files, means, the opposite of `__attribute__((warn_unused_result))`

Comment: isn't this the default setting?

Comment: @BryanChen not when bridged to swift 3

Comment: `_ = self.iDontCareOfTheReturnValue()`, maybe.

Comment: @Anish웃 It's not the answer to the question. A compiler parameter like `__attribute__((warn_unused_result))` following ObjC function declaration to make it @discardableResult when bridge to Swift 3 is what I need.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm afraid we need to add a Swift refined API for that stuff.

Comment: @ctietze Please see answer and my comment below.

Answer (score 5):

Ignoring the return value of a function is by default in ObjC and for Swift < 3.

No warning will occur if you don't capture what the method returned. But from swift 3 onwards you must use the return value and if you don't want, use `@discardable result` attribute to the method.

In ObjC, if you want to warn you can use `warn_unused_result` attribute.

```
-(int) mymethod : (int) a __attribute__((warn_unused_result)){

    return  2;

}

- (BOOL)doSomething  {

    return 2;
}



[self doSomething];
[self mymethod:2];//warning:ignoring return value of a function
```

Comment: But how I can annotate method defined in objc api to not generate warning in swift 4 ?

Comment: @Renetik I think what @LC 웃 meant is that you don't need to annotate method definition in Obj-C to not generate warning for unused return value when used in Swift code. Simply leave it as is and Swift code would treat at as if it has `@discardable result` by default. On the contrary, if you want to have default Swift >=3 behaviour for having warning for unused result, then you'd need to add `__attribute__((warn_unused_result))` for method declaration in .h file. Worked perfectly for me.

Comment: This may have been true at the time, but as of Xcode 10, you do receive a warning when using Objective C about an unused method return value.